# Using Nunit with TestCaseSource - running multiple times changes results

Tags: c#, nunit

I am writing unit tests using Nunit for a C# project.

I am trying to run a single test multiple times with different data using the `TestCaseSource` attribute.

I am doing this elsewhere without any problems, but now I am finding that the first time I run my tests, the code passes. The next time, it doesn't. Using some `Console.WriteLine` statements, I can see that the test data is different each time.

The method used to generate the data is internal to the test class, is not static and generates all required dependencies from scratch for each test.

--

I have a fake class which holds a queue of values to return when a given function is called. A new class is created for each test.

However, if the first time the test is run, it exhausts the queue, the next time it is run, no data is found. Surely this should be regenerated every time?

--

It is as if Nunit is not calling the method specified by the `TestCaseSource` attribute every time the test is run - only when the project is first loaded.

Is this expected? Is there a workaround?

EDIT:

Ok, here is a very basic example, below:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    public interface IEntry
    {
        object Read();
    }

    [TestCaseSource("TestData")]
    public void Test(Mock<IEntry> entry)
    {
        object o = entry.Object.Read();
        object o2 = entry.Object.Read();
    }

    public System.Collections.IEnumerable TestData()
    {
        var entry = new Mock<IEntry>();

        int call = 0;

        entry.Setup(x => x.Read()).Returns(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(call);
            return null;
        }).Callback(() =>
        {
            call++;
        });

        yield return new TestCaseData(entry);
    }
}
```

If you watch the test output in Nunit, it should always display 0, followed by 1. In this case, each time the test is run it will be incremented. I.e. second run: 2 and 3, third run: 4 and 5, etc.

If you move the `TestData` code into `Test`, then the correct values are returned every time.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have?

Comment: I have added a simple example using Moq which demonstrates the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the NUnit GUI runner?

What you're seeing is (I believe, I can't find confirmation in the NUnit source easily) is an optimization of the test runner.  Rather than re-create the values provided by the `TestCaseSource` attribute on every test run, it will only do so when the assembly under test changes.

If you change your code to remove the Moq dependency, it's a little clearer:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SampleTests
{
    [TestCaseSource("TestData")]
    public void Test(CallTracker callTracker)
    {
        callTracker.Call++;
        callTracker.Call++;
    }

    public IEnumerable TestData()
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData(new CallTracker());
    }

    public class CallTracker
    {
        int call;

        public int Call
        {
            get
            {
                return call;
            }
            set
            {
                call = value;
                Console.WriteLine(call);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This yields the same behavior as your code.  `CallTracker` is created anew whenever the `TestCaseSource` is evaluated, but since the call count keeps going up, the test runner must be resuing the same instance (for what I'm assuming is performance reasons).

Resharper's test runner in Visual Studio *does not* exhibit this behavior; it always shows `1` and `2` for repeated runs without recompiling.  This is probably why it's slower to start running tests than the NUnit GUI runner is.  Similarly, the NUnit console does not exhibit this behavior since it always starts cold.